# Do we need kubernetes instance to connect Eclipse Hono with Eclipse Ditto both running in sandbox environment?

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto

I would like to know whether we need kubernetes cluster as required by cloud2edge package  as mentioned in the link (https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/2018-05-02-connecting-ditto-hono.html) even if both hono and ditto are running in the sandbox environment provided for evaluation purpose ?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to deploy Hono and Ditto to your own cluster or do you want to use the Hono and Ditto sandbox environments?

Comment: @KaiHudalla - I used hono and ditto sandbox environment  individually  and able to use the API's provided for evaluation purpose . Now as a next step i wanted to know  whether  in a sandbox environment  itself can i connect  both together  or do i need  to install local setup so to be able to connect both hono and ditto together . As per documentation provided (https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/2018-05-02-connecting-ditto-hono.html) it was mentioned that i need to use cloud2edge package however it was not clear whether these instructions are for sandbox environment or only for local setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the sandboxes, you don't have the need for you own Kubernetes cluster, no.

However, using the sandboxes, you have some restrictions as you are not the "admin" of the 2 installations and therefore you e.g. can't create new tenants in Hono or create new connections in Ditto.